# Execute matlab script through C#.net

Tags: c#, matlab

I am new at C#.net and I am trying to just Execute the matlab script through visual studio C#.net.I added matlab com reference

The following is my code

MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); 
 matlab.Execute(@"cd path");

However when I run this code in visual studio, no thing appears in the matlab.

Can you please advise what is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the instructions from the official Matlab Site, it works.
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html

If you create it in the same folder as mentioned on the site, everything should work as expected. I just tried it with an WPF application.

> Create a MATLAB function, myfunc, in the folder c:\temp\example.

```
function [x,y] = myfunc(a,b,c) 
x = a + b; 
y = sprintf('Hello %s',c);
```

> and then the C# application

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 

namespace ConsoleApplication2 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            // Create the MATLAB instance 
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); 

            // Change to the directory where the function is located 
            matlab.Execute(@"cd c:\temp\example"); 

            // Define the output 
            object result = null; 

            // Call the MATLAB function myfunc
            matlab.Feval("myfunc", 2, out result, 3.14, 42.0, "world"); 

            // Display result 
            object[] res = result as object[]; 

            Console.WriteLine(res[0]); 
            Console.WriteLine(res[1]); 
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please add the most important aspects of the linked page to your answer. See discussions on meta stackoverflow, why link-only answers are bad.